# Does genitive plural take neuter verbs with years?

Tags: грамматика, impersonal

мне/тебе/ему etc. [x]" constructions tend to use было in the past tense regardless of whether or not there is an agent of the verb

someone told me this and i still quite understand it
i was given this as an example sentence:

а в Англию приехала учиться в институте, когда ей было 22 года.

i don't quite get why it is было and when to know there is an exception like this?

i have been having a hard time with these exceptions and was just looking for some advice on this stuff aswell. Should i just memorize these as they are well these types of irregularities pop up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to research the topic of **impersonal sentences**, in which the verb (and sometimes an adjective) (predicate) is always in neuter gender.

**когда ей было 22 года** is a subordinate clause and so essentially a sentence in its own right and it lacks an agent (subject) being impersonal.

**Было** is a predicate in this impersonal sentence and thus is neuter.

Another example

> Когда я проснулся, *`за окном`* ***`было`*** `ещё темно` - When i woke up ***`it was`*** `still dark outside`

Expressions indicating age always lack subject and put an object in Dative (ей). In the present tense they always lack verb - **мне 25 лет, моему ребёнку 2 года** but in past/future tense  - **мне было/будет 25 лет, моему ребёнку было/будет 2 года**.

However when the age is counted in months and days and its number ends with 1 *(bar 11 including hundreds and thousands 111 etc, 1,011 etc, 111,000 etc)* in the past tense the verb conjugates in masculine  - **был 1 месяц/день, был 21 месяц/день** and so forth.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the last part works for years as well, i.e. Мне был один год. It's a quirk of numerals ending with 1 in general.

Comment: @Alice indeed, i just didn't include years i guess because it's two words for singular (год) and plural (лет), so it's a special case